# How to insert Hebrew characters mixed with English into SQL Server without string getting reversed

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, multilingual

I'm trying to insert a string that contains Hebrew mixed with English into a SQL Server DB table. If I try to copy this string onto a query window (to build an insert statement around it), it reverses the words/characters as soon as I paste it. I tried to load the string using SSIS (from an excel), but it gets reversed before getting inserted into the sql server table. Similarly, if a user tries to type up such string into the application's UI, string gets reversed when user saves it to the database.

Thanks!

Comment: What data type is the field you're inserting it into?

Comment: nvarchar(max). collation - Hebrew_CI_AS NULL

Comment: Have you tried with prefix `N'Hebrew Characters'` before Inserting

Comment: I'd bet dollars to donuts that this is because Hebrew is a right-to-left language.

Comment: Rajesh, Yes I'm prefixing N'hebrew mixed with English' around the string. But, the string gets reversed as soon as I copy/paste it onto a Mgmt studio qry window.

Comment: Ben, it certainly appears to be an RTL issue. But it's worth noting that an all Hebrew string gets inserted without any problems. It's when string contains both Hebrew and English that I run into the reversal issue.

Comment: If you can isolate the Hebrew sub-strings, you can use REVERSE() on them.

Comment: The english words and letters in the string are also getting moved around. Because of this, I don't think using REVERSE() would work.

Comment: Can you add a sample string for us to tinker with?  Ideally both what you want and what you get instead.

Comment: I can't provide what I want since as soon as I paste it here, the string gets reversed. But here's what I end up with: 'באזור המידטאון (דורש נסיעה): Fred Meyers, בפינה של New Seward Hwy עם Northern Lights'.  I wonder if this is a windows issue. I am able to copy it into excel without reversal issues.